# Why can't I use a getAnnotation() on a reference of Annotation?

Tags: java

We can use getAnnotations() on an interface of Annotation but not getAnnotation? Why
When I changed the interface from MyAnno to Annotation in the followng program, the compiler was not recognizing the data defined in the Annotation like the str() etc...

```
package british_by_blood;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Hashingsnr {
    String str();
    int yuiop();
    double fdfd();
}


public class German_by_Descent {
    @Hashingsnr(str = "Annotation Example", yuiop = 100, fdfd = 4.267)
    public void mymeth(){
              German_by_Descent ob = new German_by_Descent();
try{
    Class c = ob.getClass();
    Method m = c.getMethod("mymeth");
    Hashingsnr anno = m.getAnnotation(Hashingsnr.class);
    System.out.println(anno.str() + " " + anno.yuiop() + " " + anno.fdfd());

}catch(NoSuchMethodException exc){
    System.out.println("Method Not Found");
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

   German_by_Descent ogb = new German_by_Descent();

    ogb.mymeth();

}

}
```

Comment: i get the following output: `Annotation Example 100 4.267` - that looks OK. You have no `MyAnno` annotation in *this* example, could you please edit your question for clarifaction on *what* your're changing actually?

Comment: Sorry, thats Hashingsnr.... Whenever i change that to Annotation in line 26(at first place), then in line 27 str, yuiop and fdfd are underlined giving error cannot find symbol

Comment: Really sorry guys, please see the 2nd comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program seems to be working correctly.  I get the following output when i run it...

```
run-single:
Annotation Example 100 4.267
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

I'm i missing something in your question?

I also changed the code to use the getAnnotations() method and recieved the same result...

```
final Annotation[] annos = m.getAnnotations();

for (Annotation anno : annos) {
    if (anno instanceof Hashingsnr) {
        final Hashingsnr impl = (Hashingsnr)anno;
        System.out.println(impl.str() + " " + impl.yuiop() + " " + impl.fdfd());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just asking why can we use getAnnotations with Annotation but not getAnnotation?

Comment: It's using inheritance because getAnnotations() can return many types of Annotations.  If you want to use the getAnnotations() you'll have to check if it is a Hashingsnr by using the 'instanceof' key word.  Check out the second code snippet where i use getAnnotations and then check if it is an instanceof.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to change this line

```
Hashingsnr anno = m.getAnnotation(Hashingsnr.class);
```

to

```
Annotation anno = m.getAnnotation(Hashingsnr.class);
```

Of course, now `anno` is of type `java.lang.annotation.Annotation` and that interface does not define your methods `str()`, `yuiop()` and `fdfd()`. That's why the compiler complains in the following line.

Like with ordinary java types, you'll have to cast back to the real annotation:

```
System.out.println(
     ((Hashingsnr) anno).str() + " " + 
     ((Hashingsnr) anno).yuiop() + " " + 
     ((Hashingsnr) anno).fdfd());
```

Comment: why can we use getAnnotations with Annotation? then

Comment: @Abhay Saini - `Annotation` does not define a `getAnnotations` method - so no, if I get your question right !?

Comment: @Abhay, you can. But you will not see the methods either. Can you post the code where you call the methods defined in `Hashingsnr` using a `Annotation` reference?. Maybe you are importing a custom defined `Annotation` or something.

Comment: @Abhay Saini - all annotations extend the interface `Annotation`. That is correct.

Comment: I think Michael.J.Lee gave a correct answer but i can't understand it.. Please can you explain it. t's using inheritance because getAnnotations() can return many types of Annotations. If you want to use the getAnnotations() you'll have to check if it is a Hashingsnr by using the 'instanceof' key word. Check out the second code snippet where i use getAnnotations and then check if it is an instanceof. –